# Troubleshoot SSIS issues

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trouble shooting an SSIS package that is failing. When I execute the package it runs 1st step but fails at the second step with the message "Execution of the job "XXXX" failed. See history log for details, history log has very little information there. Is there a way to see an exact error or generate log file with meaningful information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should modify Logging in the package so that it logs all possible things and rerun the package to see where it is failing.

But before that, you should back up the package so that you can recover from mishaps.